# Where do compiled NodeJs apps read the dotenv file from at execute time?

Tags: node.js, linux, dotenv, node-commander, node-pkg

I am writing a [commanderjs](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) app, that uses [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). The app is that is compiled using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) .

I have compiled the app for linux and moved the binary to `/usr/local/bin`, for it to be available on my `PATH`.

I am running the app from a shell script in `~/testing/myscript.sh`

When I run the script from e.g. `~/testing` where does the compiled app read the `.env` file from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads the `.env` from the executing directory, in this case `~/testing/.env`

This was originally failing because I had named the file `myapp.env`, the file must be called `.env`.

Alternatively, the config path can be set using a path in a object passed to `.config()`:

```
dotenv.config({path:'myapp.env'});
```